AcroRd32 fails to open pdf file in elevated WebView2 application with ShellExecuteW open
The webview2 application needs to open pdf file (link in local html content),
using the default pdf viewer application, which is AcroRd32.exe
The webview2 application runs in elevated mode, that is on purpose.
When clicking the pdf file link, it calls ShellExecuteW with open verb.
The AcroRd32.exe is launched but fails to open the file.
Is there other way to show pdf file when clicking the pdf link?
I installed other pdf viewer application. This one works, not when AcroRd32.exe is the default.

Security. The Elevated process launches Acrobat and blocks, Task Manager shows 'Elevated - Not allowed'.
